# Single CollectionView with multiple CollectionViewLayout.why Layout is mess up?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have Single `UICollectionView` , and I want to Apply Two different layout dynamically.

1. `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` : A Layout with same size cell and circle image.

   ```
   var flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
       let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

       flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/3, height: 140)
       flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
       flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.vertical
       flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0

       return flowLayout
   }
   ```
2. `Pintrest Layout` :
   https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

**For Example :  when user Click on Profile Button FlowLayout will be Apllied and Cell Appear with  image in Circle Shape. when user click on Picture button pintrest layout will be Applied and cell Appear with image in Rectangle shape with dynamic height.**

[image]

**intially CollectionView have 1.flowLayout and it appears perfectly.but when I click on Picture button Pintrest layout is messed up with previous layout as shown in above image.**

Following is Code For changing Layout.

```
if isGrid {
    let horizontal = flowLayout
    recentCollectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(horizontal, animated: true)
    recentCollectionView.reloadData()
}
else {
    let horizontal = PinterestLayout()
    horizontal.delegate = self
    recentCollectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(horizontal, animated: true)
    recentCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

**ViewHiarchy:**

**I have main Collection-view that Contain header and one bottom cell.cell contain other Collection-view to which I am Applying multiple layout.I have Two Different cell for each layout.I want bottom cell size equal to content Collection-view Content size so user can Scroll entire main collection-view vertically.**

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell : UICollectionViewCell!

        switch isGrid {
        case true:
            cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SearchProfileCell", for: indexPath)
            if let annotateCell = cell as? SearchProfileCell {
                annotateCell.photo = photos[indexPath.item]
            }
        case false:
             cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AnnotatedPhotoCell", for: indexPath)

            if let annotateCell = cell as? AnnotatedPhotoCell {
                annotateCell.cellwidth = collectionView.contentSize.width/3
                annotateCell.photo = photos[indexPath.item]

            }
        }

        cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 0
        return cell
    }
```

Code of profile and picture button Action.

```
@IBAction func pictureClick(sender:UIButton) {
        isGrid = false
        self.searchCollectionView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func profilClick(sender:UIButton) {
        isGrid = true
        self.searchCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: try performBatchUpdates

Comment: do you mean instead of reloadData i should use PerformBatchUpdate right?

Comment: Inside block of performBatchUpdate put your layout reset code

Comment: okay.let me try

Comment: I would think you should use layoutSubviews instead of reloadData() so after your IF Statement try self.view.layoutSubviews. You want to trigger a redraw of the view controller

Comment: are you using different cell for both layout or same collection cell ?

Comment: Simple option would be to use two collectionViews here instead of resetting the  layout.

Comment: hi @PrashantTukadiya thanks for your suggestion.but , PerformBatch update not working.After PerformBathupdate have same Result as shown in image.

Comment: hi @Alexander layOutSubView Also not Working.

Comment: @JatinKathrotiya yes i have two diffrent Cell for each layout.

Comment: i have updated my answer please check it

Comment: @Bhavesh.iosDev: Have you got sol for your question. I need your help.

Comment: yes, I got.how can I help You....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are using two different layout even though you can achieve same Result with pintrestLayout.  https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest.

Check pintrestLayout carefully , it have Delegate for Dynamic height.

```
 let photoHeight = delegate.collectionView(collectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath: indexPath)
```

if you return static height here , your pintrest layout become GridLayout(your First Layout).

if you want pintrest layout as work for both layout , you need to declare same Boolean(isGrid) in pintrest layout.and use this boolean to return UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

more important  raywenderlich pintrest layout uses cache to store layout attribute.you have to remove cache object before applying other layout.

Check in this tutorial , how same layout used for grid,list and linear.
https://benoitpasquier.com/optimise-uicollectionview-swift/

what you need in your layout.

```
 var isGrid : Bool = true {
        didSet {
            if isGrid != oldValue {
                cache.removeAll()
                self.invalidateLayout()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi could you please give some code example that illustrate how single layout work for diffrent design.

Answer (score 2):

I think problem is not inside layout but might be inside cellForItemAt. if you are using different cell for both layout then do not compare bool at cellForItemAt method. you should compare layout class type
like below code :

```
 func  collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if collectionView.collectionViewLayout.isKind(of: PinterestLayout.self) {
           // return cell for PinterestLayout 
             guard let annotateCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SearchProfileCell", for: indexPath) as? SearchProfileCell else {
              fatalError("SearchProfileCell Not Found")
            }
            annotateCell.photo = photos[indexPath.item]
            return annotateCell
        } else {
         // return cell for flowLayout 
              guard let annotateCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AnnotatedPhotoCell", for: indexPath) as? AnnotatedPhotoCell else {
                fatalError("AnnotatedPhotoCell Not Found")
             }
             annotateCell.cellwidth = collectionView.contentSize.width/3
             annotateCell.photo = photos[indexPath.item]
             return annotateCell
        }
 }
```

Also need to update layout change action methods like:

```
     @IBAction func pictureClick(sender:UIButton) {
               isGrid = false

        self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()  
       self.collectionView?.setCollectionViewLayout(PinterestLayout(), 
             animated: false, completion: { [weak self] (complite) in
                    guard let strongSelf = self else {
                        return
                    }
                    strongSelf.searchCollectionView?.reloadData()
                })
       }

      @IBAction func profilClick(sender:UIButton) {
          isGrid = true
          self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()              
       self.collectionView?.setCollectionViewLayout(flowLayout, 
             animated: false, completion: { [weak self] (complite) in
                    guard let strongSelf = self else {
                        return
                    }
                    strongSelf.searchCollectionView?.reloadData()
                })
     }
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion.i have replaced your code of cellforindexpath, but still have same problem.

Comment: Can you try setCollectionViewLayout with completion block?